# eclipse pdt and drupal: code completion question

Tags: eclipse, drupal, eclipse-pdt

I'm quite new to eclipse ptd and drupal; I'm struggling with code completion..

I'm using Suse 11.3, eclipse pdt 2.2.0, installed xdebug 2.1.2.

### Inside of my drupal installation directory I have added following php script file:

```
<?php

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$body_text = 'This is the body text I want entered with the node';

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'article';
node_object_prepare($node);

$node->title    = 'Node Created Programmatically on ' . date('c');
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

$node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $body_text;
$node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($body_text);
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';

$path = 'content/programmatically_created_node_' . date('YmdHis');
$node->path = array('alias' => $path);

node_save($node);
```

### ?>

So - this an example from web that allows to add a node programatically.
This one works fine for me - adds a new node when executed.

The problem is that I cannot see code completion hints when I start to type
for example: "$node->"  (No completions available.)

Should that work? What could I do wrong with my setup that I don't get it working ?

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no possibility to get such completition.

BTW, You could use this Drupal module for better Ecliipse / Drupal integration :
http://drupal.org/project/eclipse

Comment: Thanks for response; I have installed the module pointed above, but I don't understand how should I use it - and I don't see any good examples on the web...

Comment: check README.txt of the module.

Comment: Yes, I have read the README - it tells about installation - did not have problems with that at all. But still I don't know how to use it..? I see these hooks to popup when I try to do autocompletion for things like "hook_..." - but what next ?